# Need a concrete example of fit_generator()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm making a speech recognition model with an input shape of (56088,22050,1) which as a whole can be loaded from a .npy file(~5GB in size) into the memory but I wanted to figure out a better way. I came across the keras fit_generator() method but most examples were based on mnist and used the ImageDataGenerator() function. I realised that I had to make a custom generator function but I wasn't really sure how. As per [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1627) thread, I referenced his generator function to make something like this but I still have to load the entire data to memory which takes a **lot** of time. Plus I'm uncertain if this program would run at all because it doesn't output anything at all for the first 20 minutes that I ran it for
Any other way out?

```
import librosa
import glob
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np


class_list, X_train, Y_train = [],[],[]
filename = "D:\\SpeechRecognitionData\\train\\audio\\"

class_names = os.listdir(filename)
print(class_names)

for classes in class_names:
    if classes == '_background_noise_':
        continue
    else:
        class_list.append(''.join(filename+classes))

print(class_list,"\n",len(class_list))


def create_X(address):
    wave,sr = librosa.load(address)
    wave.reshape(-1,1)
    yield wave


def getLabel(filename):
    base_name = os.path.basename(filename)
    return base_name

def onehot(Y_train):
    from sklearn import preprocessing
    enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
    Y_train = Y_train.reshape(-1,1)
    enc.fit(Y_train)
    Y_train = enc.transform(Y_train).toarray()
    return Y_train


def execute(X_train, Y_train):
    loop = 0
    for i in class_list:
        c=0
        loop+=1
        for file in glob.glob("".join(i+"\\*.wav")): # iterating through each .wav audio file in the directory to create training data
            if np.array(list(create_X(file))).shape[0] == 22050:
                c+=1
                Y_train.append(class_names.index(getLabel(i)))
                X_train.append(create_X(file))
                if c%100==0:
                    print("{} files processed in loop {}".format(c,loop))

    while 1:
        for i in range(1558): # 36*1558 = 56088
            if i%125==0:
                print("i= "+str(i))
            yield np.array(X_train[i*36:(i+1)*36]).reshape(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],1), onehot(np.array(Y_train[i*36:(i+1)*36]))


input_shape = (22050,1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(16,activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape,kernel_size=(10)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32,activation='relu',kernel_size=(10)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(16,activation='relu',kernel_size=(10)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(30,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
generator = execute(X_train,Y_train)
model.fit_generator(generator,steps_per_epoch=56088//36,shuffle=True)
model.save("model.h5")
```

Comment: go through [this](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) link, it has exactly what you require

Comment: @SiddhantTandon I did go through this but I couldn't understand what the ID thing is. It's very vaguely described and I couldn't find any other article using this method. It'd be great if you could help me out by explaining the intent/logic behind quoted that approach

Comment: to simply explain the ID thing, the indexes of samples are stored as list for both train and validation. And your labels , its simply a dict with keys and indexes and values as labels. Think like a dataframe of labels with indexes.

Comment: in your code i see that you process all of your `.wav`files in one go and keep appending to the list, then later you generate samples from this complete list. Why not try to do this in batches, for ex: process 20 wave files append to list and `yield` these 20 processed samples ? and keep doing it untill all .wav files are consumed ?

Comment: just try to do the `yield`operation inside the for loop in periodic intervals.

Comment: @SiddhantTandon Thanks for the help. I actually followed another method which I found here "https://github.com/tjh48/keras_generators/blob/master/keras_generator_example.ipynb. This worked well for me after I split my data into a few npy files. Thanks for the help!

Comment: would mind posting your answer ? it will surely help others.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out by looking at this example here- https://github.com/tjh48/keras_generators/blob/master/keras_generator_example.ipynb

If someone comes across this then they can refer to my notebook
https://github.com/DarshanDeshpande/Speech-Recognition/blob/master/SpeechRecognitionWithGenerators.ipynb

Thanks!